# JavaScript Calculator using HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a calculator that, using JavaScript, takes a number from an HTML input box like this one.

```js
// Take form input and multiply by four
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input placeholder="Side Length of Square"/>
  </body>  
</html>
```

How could I then relay the user input, say 5, so that the JavaScript would take "5" and multiply it to find the area of the square? This is my first question ever on Stack Overflow, so I apologize if I did something wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: We are not hear to do your homework. What did you try?

Comment: @J. Smith, you should think of StackOverflow as a last resort. Only post here when all other means of finding a solution have been exhausted. To solve this issue, google things like 'how to pass html input value to javascript'. Chances are, there is probably already a question asked on SO about this issue that will also answer your question. Please read this helpful howto for asking questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ethilium, I'm sorry for my ignorance, but this is my first-ever Stack Overflow question. Next time, I will be more strenuous in finding other online resources.

Comment: @J. Smith. No worries. That's why I didn't down vote your question. But I can't speak for others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use javascript's onkeyup to calculate the area of a square as the user types in numbers. Check out the code below!

```js
function calc(){
var val=document.getElementById("myInput").value;
document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=Math.pow(val, 2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="Side Length of Square"onkeyup="calc()"/>
    <p>Area : <span id="area"></span></p>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I would replace "onkeyup" with "oninput", so it calculates the answer instantly and also works on touchscreen.

Comment: Yes, it is very much exactly what I was looking for. Other than a bit of unclean code that is really only an issue because I have ridiculous OCD ;), it is perfect!

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide where you want to place your output, e.g. introduce a new `<div>` element whose text content will hold the computed side length.

Also, you should give your `<input>` as well as your output `<div>` a unique `id` attribute so you can identify it later on from within your JavaScript code.

Then, you would introduce a new `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag. This guarantees that at the time of script execution, all relevant HTML elements have already been loaded and added to the Document Object Model (DOM) so that your script can access them.

Finally, you write a JavaScript "input" event handler and attach it to the `<input>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="side-length" placeholder="Side Length of Square">
    <div id="area"></div>
    <script>
      let input = document.getElementById("side-length");
      let output = document.getElementById("area");
      input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        let sideLength = input.valueAsNumber;
        output.textContent = sideLength * sideLength;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: Above event handler computes the *area* of the square with given side length, as per your question and opposed to the comment above your code snippet.